# Draw ellipse on the center of blob

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, bitmap, aforge

**Hello,
I'm new C# user and I searched for easy method for drawing an ellipse on the blob, the center is blob center.
Firstly, I used OpenCvSharp.Blob name space but I could not get the center. I used Emu.CV and Aforge.Net also but the center is not achieved.
Which library can get the center in the form of X,Y?
Thanks**

I used this code but also get wrong center:

```
foreach (Blob blob in blobs)
            {
                //Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)picConnComp.Image;
                //Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
                if (blob.Rectangle.Width > 50)
                {

                    // the blob looks interesting, let's extract it
                    g.DrawEllipse(redPen,
                (float)(blob.CenterOfGravity.X), (float)(blob.CenterOfGravity.Y),
                (float)(blob.Image.Width / 2), (float)(blob.Image.Height / 2));
                }
```

Comment: See OpenCV Doc [Creating Bounding rotated boxes and ellipses for contour](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If using AForge.NET framework you can get rectangle directly from blob as follows:

```
Rectangle rect = blob.Rectangle;
```

Afterwards you can draw an ellipse of blobs size like this:

```
...    
g1.DrawEllipse(redPen, rect);
...
```